# Redirecting from index route fails

Tags: ember.js

In my application, the `index` route is unused. It's mainly there to redirect to the proper route. Right now, it redirects to the `matrix` route. Here's the route (full code):

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('matrix');
    }
});
```

This code fails. I get an error caught in the `application` route. The `error` parameter is undefined, but the `transition` parameter is defined. The `transition` parameter shows the `targetName` to be `index`, even though I was redirecting to `matrix`.

Going to the `matrix` route directly via the URL works fine. No issues. And if I change the `redirect` hook to either `beforeModel` or `afterModel`, it works fine. But as it stands, the redirect fails. What could be causing this? Am I using the hook the wrong way?